# $\bar zz^3+z\bar z^3=350$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z=x+iy$ be a complex number where $x$ and $y$ are integers. Then find the area of the rectangle whose vertices are the roots of the equation $\bar zz^3+z\bar z^3=350$.

P.S- While typing my doubt here, I got clarity of what I was doing, and solved this accidentally. Didn't want to waste all the efforts, so, I have pasted my solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z\bar z(z^2+\bar z^2)=|z|^2(z^2+\bar z^2)=(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2+2xyi+x^2-y^2-2xyi)=2(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)$$

Therefore, $$(x^2+y^2)(x^2-y^2)=175=25*7=(16+9)(16-9)$$

So, $x=\pm 4, y= \pm 3$. Therefore the area is $8*6=48$.

Comment: You still have to explain why there are no other solutions.

Comment: @Bernard The question states that the solutions are vertices of a rectangle hence there must only be $4$ possible solutions for $z$.

Comment: And if there was an error in the problem?

Comment: @Bernard . $ 175 =|x|^4-|y|^4\ge (|y|+1)^4-|y|^4>4|y|^3 .$ So $3\ge |y|.$ And  so $|x|^4=175 +|y|^4\le 175 +3^4$. Etc.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Rewriting it (x^2-y^2)(x2+y2)=175$, it can be much simpler: find the divisor(s) of $175$ which are sums of two squares.